# Phishing email from a contact

Tags: email, phishing, spam

I received an email from what looked like a friend, it had a suspicious link I inspected the email address and saw that the username was spot on but the domain name was totally different.  I also put the link through a suspicious link checker and it came through as such.  The username is quite a unique one I'm very suspicious as it feels like a personal attack.  That said I don't how these phishing people operate so am asking for your thoughts

Comment: When you say "the username was spot on but the domain name was totally different", presumably you are comparing it to your friend's email address. If the domain name is different, then surely you now know that it isn't from your friend. Given that you've said all this in your question, it's unclear to me what you expect anyone else to be able to tell you... Are you able to clarify your question?

Comment: You are correct I did know it was not from a friend.  My question is, is it likely am I being targeted personally as the username is very unique.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific? Right now your question is "asking for your thoughts". What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: I would like your thoughts\answers on the chances of this being a personal attack and not a random attack considering the username etc.

Comment: Most likely, it is just a random phishing e-mail. But it is impossible to be more affirmative than that without more information.

Comment: @A.Hersean what other information would be useful?

Comment: The full content of the e-mail, with the names or pseudonyms of real persons removed for privacy concerns (along any information that could be used to identify one). The headers of the e-mail could be useful too, but (a) it yould be harder to "anonymize" them and (b) how to get them depends on your e-mail reader: I can't give you a method for it, you'll have to look up how to do that by yourself. With the content of the e-mail, we could ask you more questions (if needed) to make a good guess of whether it was a targeted e-mail.

Comment: I know it's not genuine as they both came through to my spam box which it sometimes does for legit emails.  There was no header and a link that I copied and pasted and has been identified as phishing.  The body of the email was my name as the greeting, the link and a sign off using the first name and surname of sender (pretend sender). Is it safe to put the link in here?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to bring your attention to a malware called **Trickbot**. This [TrendMicro article on Trickbot](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1122411-trickbot-s-newly-released-modules-makes-it-even-trickier) should bring you up to speed.

I have worked with the malware a couple of times in recent months and you might be interested in *one* of its capabilities.

It is able to steal email credentials & address-books. The compromised sender email address will then be used to **spoof** the subsequent mass emails to the potential victims in the address-book.

Essentially by doing this, the chances of this malware infecting another user by clicking it is way higher. The intention is to let the **victim's guard down** by putting a familiar name to the malicious email. Victims would assume that the sender is legitimate, like a friend or a colleague, and would then click the link and compromised itself and the cycle continues. So let's say an address book of 150 recipients, all it takes is one out of the 150 to keep the chain going.

You might've witnessed this malware first hand, notify your friend through proper channels, and see what is going on.

> as it feels like a personal attack.

I can see why you would feel this way, I am not ruling out the personal attack reasoning. But I am just letting you know that there is a way that there are ***automated/customized* personal attacks** being crafted where you are just a potential victim of another victim.

Comment: Appreciate your response.  Just to give some further information.  I had 1 email on Thursday from friend 1 and then a second email today from friend 2 who is friend 1s partner?  It looks and feels like first attempt didn't work so...